# jquery - function returns "null" - how to check for this?

Tags: jquery, function

I have a function in Jquery Mobile called findclosestLink, that checks what is clicked when the user clicks on screen.

Looks like this:

```
var link = find(findClosestLink(event.target);

findClosestLink: function (ele) {
   var self = this;
   while (ele){
     if (ele.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "a"){
         break;
         }
      ele = ele.parentNode; 
      }
      console.log(ele);
      return ele;
   }
```

If I click somewhere in the screen **ele** consoles as "null" and my variable becomes "[]".

Question: how can I check for this empty something "[]"?

All of these don't work:

```
if ( link == 'null' ) { console.log("null"); }
if ( link == '' ) { console.log("empty");}
if ( link == 'undefined' ) { console.log("undefined"); }
if ( link == []) { console.log("empty object"); }
if ( link == $() ) { console.log("empty dings"); }
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: try it with typeof in front. Example `if ( typeof link == 'null' ) ... `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean check for empty array? Use the `length` property:

```
console.log([].length); // 0
```

so:

```
// 0 is 'falsy', so...
if(!ele.length) {
    // empty
}
```

Comment: yes indeed... THANKS! also for improving my dictionary of jquery terms. One "something" to remove ;-)

Comment: Actually your edit is not correct, I think. I want to do nothing if the array is empty. Checking for !ele.length will still fire, because ele.length = 0. If I check for ele.length != 0, then it works.

Answer (score 0):

To explain my comment a bit more:

```
if ( typeof link == 'null' ) { console.log("null"); }
if ( link == '' ) { console.log("empty");}
if (  typeof link == 'undefined' ) { console.log("undefined"); }
if (  typeof link == 'object') { console.log("empty object"); }

or 

switch(typeof link) {
    case 'null':
        console.log('is null');
        break;
    [....]
}
```

Comment: the below is working fine and is easier = if (link.length == 0). This function fires a lot so I don't want to slow things down. Thanks anyway!